# Summing day data values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv, sum

I need help on my program with how to add up each day values. So far it looks like this

```
import csv

def convert(data):
    try:
        return int(data)
    except ValueError:
        return 0

with open('MonthData1.csv', 'r') as file1:
        read_file = csv.reader(file1, delimiter = ';')
        delheader = next(read_file)
        for line in read_file: 
            valuedata = max(0,sum([convert(i) for i in line[1:5]])) 
            print(line[0], valuedata)
```

At the moment it sums the 3 item values as it should:

```
1.5.2018 15:00 150
1.5.2018 20:00 95
2.5.2018 18:00 105
4.5.2018 17:00 78
4.5.2018 20:00 0
4.5.2018 20:00 9
```

But I want it to sum all the values of the same day, so it would be something like this:

```
1.5.2018 245
2.5.2018 105
4.5.2018 87
```

How could this be excecuted? I hope for help. Here is a pastebin from all the data used in this: https://pastebin.com/Tw4aYdPc
The base code is not mine originally, edited it a bit to match my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a `defaultdict` to sum your valuedatas and ordered it to print:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict, OrderedDict


def convert(data):
    try:
        return int(data)
    except ValueError:
        return 0


with open('MonthData1.csv', 'r') as file1:
        read_file = csv.reader(file1, delimiter=';')
        delheader = next(read_file)
        data = defaultdict(int)
        for line in read_file:
            valuedata = max(0, sum([convert(i) for i in line[1:5]]))
            data[line[0].split()[0]] += valuedata

        for key in OrderedDict(sorted(data.items())):
            print('{} {}'.format(key, data[key]))
```

**EDIT:**
To calculate cumulative values:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict, OrderedDict


def convert(data):
    try:
        return int(data)
    except ValueError:
        return 0


with open('MonthData1.csv', 'r') as file1:
        read_file = csv.reader(file1, delimiter=';')
        delheader = next(read_file)
        data = defaultdict(int)
        for line in read_file:
            valuedata = max(0, sum([convert(i) for i in line[1:5]]))
            data[line[0].split()[0]] += valuedata

        previous_values = []
        for key, value in OrderedDict(sorted(data.items())).items():
            print('{} {}'.format(key, value + sum(previous_values)))
            previous_values.append(value)
```

Results:

> 1.5.2018 245
>
> 2.5.2018 350
>
> 4.5.2018 433

Comment: Wow thank you very much. Is it possible to add that after it has printed sums of the days, it calculates the cumulative values?  It would pretty much be like: 1.5.2018 245, 2.5.2018 350, 4.5.2018  437
This would be helpful for me to analyze the values

Comment: After each day it maintains the value and sums the next values to the current one

Comment: Can you print first the normal sum, and after it has printed the normal values it would print the cumulative values, something like this:1.5.2018 245 2.5.2018 105 4.5.2018 87  Then straight after it prints these 1.5.2018 245, 2.5.2018 350, 4.5.2018 437

Comment: If both loops are doing what you want, could't you simply put both of them in your code?

Comment: If you want you can do some improvements like only converting the dict to `OrderedDict` once.

Comment: Ah, I am so sorry, I didn't notice that you just added a edit and didn't delete the first code that you wrote. Massive thank you, this does excactly what I wanted! The next part is to save the data to a new csv file, but I think I can do it.  Thank you once more!